# Discord.py delete only the latest message by reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want to delete a message by reacting with a trash emoji. My only problem is, that all messages by the one person get deleted when reacting.

So first it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBBWh.png

And after reacting to the second "trash" emoji, all four message are deleted.

Thank you! :)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if not (message.author.bot):
            
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Points earned!", description="+1 Points")
            msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            await message.add_reaction("️")

            channel = message.channel

            def check(reaction, user):
                return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '️'
                
            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await channel.send("This shouldnt happen")
            else:
                await msg.delete()
                await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never checked for the correct message. When you react to one of them, it triggers the checks for both messages and both are deleted. What you want is this:

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '️' and reaction.message.id == message.id
```

This checks that the message you were reacting to is equal to the original message.
This way, the reaction will only trigger for the message that it reacted to.